# How to have an excel file that gets updated for every jenkins run and use the updated excel file for next jenkins run?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, cucumber, testng

I have a selenium cucumber framework repo that resides in git. I have an excel file that store the data (ex. customerIds) and I will have to use that data in subsequent run. Now I have added the excel sheet in git repo. Now when I rerun the build, jenkins pulls the data which is there in the git repo but not from the previous run's excel sheet.

Note:- I am deleting the workspace before the build starts. I have tried to exclude the file using the pattern
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way to properly preserve data from one run to another (apart from source control) is to use archived artifacts. You'll need to do this in two stages.

Stage 1:

- run the job like it's the first time; you will have no Excel file present
- at the end of the job, archive the Excel file as an artifact

Stage 2:

- update the job to download the same artifact from the job itself; the Excel file will be present in your job now
- at the end of the job, archive the now updated Excel file (you shouldn't have to make any changes to your job)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had to exclude .git folder as well to exclude my excel file. Now Jenkins clone all other files except my excel file. Thanks for the support.